# Rake clean raise error when the file does not exist

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a Rakefile like this

```
task :clean do
  sh 'rm ./foo'
end
```

I want to prevent it from reporting error when the file 'foo' does not exist. How to do that?

I think what I want is: Is there a way to check the file first and then decide what to do next.

For example:

```
file 'aaa' => 'bbb' do
  sh 'cp bbb aaa'
end
```

This task depends on the existence of file 'bbb', so I want to know `can I tell Rake that my task depends on the` **non-existence** `of file 'foo'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by extending rake a bit:

Rakefile:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'unfile_rake_ext')

unfile 'target.txt' do
  File.delete('target.txt')
end
```

unfile_rake_ext.rb:

```
class UnFileTask < Rake::FileTask
  def needed?
    File.exist?(name)
  end
end

def unfile(*args, &block)
  UnFileTask.define_task(*args, &block)
end
```

And my console output:

```
D:\Projects\ZPersonal\tmp>ls
Rakefile  unfile_rake_ext.rb

D:\Projects\ZPersonal\tmp>touch target.txt && ls
Rakefile  target.txt  unfile_rake_ext.rb

D:\Projects\ZPersonal\tmp>rake target.txt --trace
** Invoke target.txt (first_time)
** Execute target.txt

D:\Projects\ZPersonal\tmp>ls
Rakefile  unfile_rake_ext.rb

D:\Projects\ZPersonal\tmp>rake target.txt --trace
** Invoke target.txt (first_time, not_needed)

D:\Projects\ZPersonal\tmp>ls
Rakefile  unfile_rake_ext.rb
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your rakefile:

```
task :clean do
  rm 'foo' if File.exists? 'foo'
end

file 'aaa' => ['bbb', :clean] do |t|
  cp t.prerequisites[0], t.name
end
```

Now at the command line:

```
echo 'test' > bbb
rake aaa
    => cp bbb aaa

touch foo
rake aaa
    => rm foo
    => cp bbb aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if File.exists? './foo/'
  sh 'rm -f ./foo'
end
```

Comment: well. That's a solution. What I really want is to check some condition and decide what to do or not to do. Thanks.

Comment: Aha, so, something like `sh 'rm ./foo' if File.exists? './foo'`?

Comment: Thanks, see my new edit. I really want to rake to handle that, not by my code. :)